# Using ROC value as a threshold in confusion matrix

Tags: roc, threshold, confusion-matrix

Is it possible to use AUC value as a threshold to build the confusion matrix?

Comment: What is "ROC value"? Do you mean sensitivity/specificity at a threshold, or AUC, or ?

Comment: Yes, I mean is AUC.

Comment: Needs more information.